# Group rows but keep values where not null

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I am trying to group rows in MySQL but end up with a wrong result.

My DB looks like this:
[image: ScreenDump]

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT 
    r_id, va_id,va_klasse,va_periode, 
    1va_mer,1va_hjem,1va_mot,1va_bil,1va_fit,1va_hand,1va_med,1va_fra, 
    2va_mer,2va_hjem,2va_trae,2va_bil,2va_sty,2va_mus,2va_med,2va_fra,
    3va_mer,3va_hjem,3va_mot,3va_bil,3va_pima,3va_nat,3va_med,3va_fra,
    va_lock, va_update

FROM o6hxd_valgfag
WHERE va_klasse IN('7A','7B','7C','8A','8B','8C','9A','9B','9C')
GROUP BY va_id
ORDER BY va_klasse,va_name
```

This produces a wrong result, where one row is returned with only the first three numbers 123 and not the ones from row two and three.
What I would like is a result where the numbers 123, 321 and 132 are gathered in one line.

I can explain more detailed if this isn't sufficient.

Comment: Sorry if you already know that but if you want to select all the columns you can just use the `*` instead of writing the names of all the columns.

Comment: If they all belong in the same row, you should insert or update them into the same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If across those fields there should only be ever one value, you should really have them all in the same record and go about fixing it to insert and update the same record.

Ie I am aware that you database isn't designed correctly 
However
To dig you out, you could give this a crack, I suppose.

```
SELECT 
    r_id, va_id,va_klasse,va_periode, 
    MAX(1va_mer),MAX(1va_hjem),MAX(1va_mot),MAX(1va_bil),MAX(1va_fit),MAX(1va_hand),MAX(1va_med),MAX(1va_fra), 
    MAX(2va_mer),MAX(2va_hjem),MAX(2va_trae),MAX(2va_bil),MAX(2va_sty),MAX(2va_mus),MAX(2va_med),MAX(2va_fra),
    MAX(3va_mer),MAX(3va_hjem),MAX(3va_mot),MAX(3va_bil),MAX(3va_pima),MAX(3va_nat),MAX(3va_med),MAX(3va_fra),
    va_lock, va_update

FROM o6hxd_valgfag
WHERE va_klasse IN('7A','7B','7C','8A','8B','8C','9A','9B','9C')
GROUP BY va_id
ORDER BY va_klasse,va_name
```

Comment: Thanks - allready tried with max but no luck - Will redesign my table and go for the "one-row'er" - with flexibility comes complexity 

Answer (score 1):

Your query will not work as intended. Think about this use-case:

what if for row1 `(r_id =9)`, the fields `2va_sty, 2va_mus, 2va_med` are not empty and has values?

In such case what should your desired output be? It certainly cannot be the  numbers 123, 321 and 132 gathered in one line. Group by is usually used if you want to use aggregate functions executed against a certain field value, in your case `va_id`.

Comment: They will never have values as they are not equal to va_periode 1.

Comment: Thats right - I might have to use va_periode in two subqueries!? In a way to sort the ones with values - or ...  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution to your problem but i think a better query would be like this (because of the not named columns in the group by clause https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html):

```
SELECT 
    aa.r_id, aa.va_id, aa.va_klasse, aa.va_periode, 
    aa.1va_mer, aa.1va_hjem, aa.1va_mot, aa.1va_bil, aa.1va_fit, aa.1va_hand, aa.1va_med, aa.1va_fra, 
    aa.2va_mer, aa.2va_hjem, aa.2va_trae, aa.2va_bil, aa.2va_sty,2va_mus, aa.2va_med, aa.2va_fra,
    aa.3va_mer, aa.3va_hjem, aa.3va_mot, aa.3va_bil, aa.3va_pima, aa.3va_nat, aa.3va_med, aa.3va_fra,
    aa.va_lock, aa.va_update
FROM o6hxd_valgfag AS aa
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT va_id
    FROM o6hxd_valgfag
    GROUP BY va_id
) AS _aa
ON aa.va_id = _aa.va_id
WHERE aa.va_klasse IN ('7A','7B','7C','8A','8B','8C','9A','9B','9C')
ORDER BY aa.va_klasse, aa.va_name;
```